# pythonscript with call function for another pythonscript doesn't work with cron

Tags: python, cron, call

I run a python script every 10 min (crontab) which monitors uptime to warn me about any reboot.
If any reboot it sends me an email. There is a python email script which I call when there has been a reboot and send email ( smtplib ). When I run the main script manually everything works just as intended. Email is sent. When I run from a crontab every 10 min as a user the email is not sent. I run the script in Ubuntu. Here follows the code:

```
from subprocess import call
from datetime import date
import psutil
import time
import datetime

td = datetime.datetime.now()
today = td.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M')

logpath1  = '/home/jim/usb/logs/uptime_boot.log'
logpath2  = '/home/jim/usb/logs/uptime.log'

def seconds_elapsed():
    return time.time() - psutil.boot_time()

uptime = seconds_elapsed()
optime = str(int(uptime))

if uptime <  660:
    #print("There was a reboot: "+ today )
    with open(logpath1, "a") as file1:
        #Writing data to a file
        file1.write("Reboot < 11 min ago: "+ today+"\n")
        call(["/usr/bin/python3","/home/jim/usb/pythons/send_epost1.py"])

if uptime > 660:
    #print("No reboot: "+ today )
    with open(logpath2, "a") as file1:
        #Writing data to a file
        file1.write("No reboot yet: "+ today+" Uptime: "+optime+" secs."+"\n")
```

Called python email script:

```
import os
from email.message import EmailMessage
import ssl
import smtplib

email_sender = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
email_passw  = os.environ.get("zohopwd") 
email_receiv = 'xxxxxb@gmail.com'

subject = 'NEPTUN reboot'
body = """
Neptun reboot.
"""

em = EmailMessage()
em['From'] = email_sender
em['To'] = email_receiv
em['Subject'] = subject
em.set_content(body) 

context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465, context=context) as smtp:
    smtp.login(email_sender,email_passw)
    smtp.sendmail(email_sender, email_receiv, em.as_string())
```

1. I tried to run manually it works perfect, with nothing in crontab.
2. The script runs with crontab with the call function but skips the call function.
3. I have checked cat /var/log/syslog it says the script was executed

Comment: Are you running the crontab as yourself, or as a different user?

Comment: I run it as a myself. I run crontab -e as jim

Comment: Hmm..., I can see that you get a value from the environment.  On Linux (or other Unix-like) systems, most environment values are loaded by the *profile* files at login time... and are not available from cron jobs. I can remember using commands close to `source /home/name/.profile; /path/to/command params` in crontabs.

Comment: I'm going to guess the problem is with the `os.environ.get("zohopwd")` call.  The crontab is running in a different environment than you're used to, and that variable isn't set.

Comment: crontabs usually run with the plain `sh` shell.  What is your default login shell?  Is it something else, like zsh or csh?

Comment: John Gordon: My default login shell is bash. Seems I should try to eliminate the os.environ.get("zohopwd"). I will try and get back with a comment.

Comment: by removing os.environ.get("zohopwd") it helped and it works well now.